# How to get a selected item in drop-down list?

Tags: html, go

I have the following html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<select name="action" size="1" id="action-choice">
    <option value="test">Test</option>
    <option value="run">Run</option>
</select>
```

how to get the value of the selected option using Go?

```
func main() {
    log.Println("started")
    http.HandleFunc("/upload", upload)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
}


func upload(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if r.Method == "GET" {
        t, _ := template.ParseFiles("upload.html")
        t.Execute(w, nil)
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing first you have to have a form and submit button in your html to send data to a route . There is no form in your html.

```
<form method="post" action"/upload">
<select name="action" size="1" id="action-choice">
    <option value="test">Test</option>
    <option value="run">Run</option>
</select>
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Second: in your upload function you can do this :

```
r.ParseForm()
fmt.Println(r.Form["action"])
```

Answer (score 2):

The Go code is acting as the server and since the HTML file is running from the user's browser, you can't access it without sending it to the server. In this example I will be using HTTP GET.

Assuming that your html file is under "/"

First, change the html file to use a GET form:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form action="/upload" method="get">
<select name="action" size="1" id="action-choice">
    <option value="test">Test</option>
    <option value="run">Run</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Now, we need to catch this GET request under /upload (since the form is redirecting to /upload)

```go
func upload(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if r.Method == "GET" {
        r.ParseForm()
        w.Write([]byte(r.Form["action"][0]))
    }
}
```

so we can sum it all up to the following GO code

```go
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    "log"
)


var page = `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form action="/upload" method="get">
<select name="action" size="1" id="action-choice">
    <option value="test">Test</option>
    <option value="run">Run</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>`
func m(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Write([]byte(page))
}

func upload(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if r.Method == "GET" {
        r.ParseForm()
        w.Write([]byte(r.Form["action"][0]))
    }
}
func main() {
    log.Println("started")
    http.HandleFunc("/", m)
    http.HandleFunc("/upload", upload)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
}
```